# Get values of all child EditBoxes

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is this code **completely** correct or not?

```
myRLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rel_layout );

for(int i = 0; i < myRLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
View v = myRLayout.getChildAt(i);
if(v instanceof EditText) {
       TextView res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
       String str1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_1)).getText().toString();
       String str2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_2)).getText().toString();
       res.setText(str1+str2);
    }
}
```

Why I ask? For each iteration only one EditText gets in action or all together at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `v` instance of Child to get value from all `EditText` and use `TextView.append` for showing values in `TextView`. try it as:

```
TextView res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
res.setText(""); //<< clear textview here
for(int i = 0; i < myRLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
 View v = myRLayout.getChildAt(i);
 if(v instanceof EditText) {
       String str1 = v.getText().toString();  //<< get text from ith EditText
       res.append(str1);  // append value to result_text TextView
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. but I need these strings convert to floats and make some computatons with them...

Comment: @user2230842: if you want to perform computations on EditText values then first all values in ArrayList and then use ArrayList for converting string to floats and perform computations before showing it TextView